TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'BatchNormalization'
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'BatchNormalization' using config={'name': 'bn_conv1', 'trainable': False, 'momentum': 0.99, 'epsilon': 1e-05, 'center': True, 'scale': True, 'beta_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'gamma_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'moving_mean_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'moving_variance_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}}, 'beta_regularizer': None, 'gamma_regularizer': None, 'beta_constraint': None, 'gamma_constraint': None, 'freeze': True}.

Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to BatchNormalization: {'freeze': True}

This is the problem that I've got while working with ImageAI object detection.
I don't really know what to do with it, so I'll try everything that you'll say. Thank you

Hi @Jason More, To resolve this issue, modify the layer configuration. You can manually remove the 'freeze': True argument from the layer's configuration, Second point: sometime this error comes because you are not using the latest version of ImageAI Version, which is not compatible with TensorFlow/Keras APIs. Please share the code so that I can help you more.
